# Existence and uniqueness of weights for the rule $\int_a^b f(x) \ = \ \sum_{0 \leq k \leq n} w_k f(x_k)$

Tags: integration, polynomials, numerical-methods, matrix-equations

I want to establish this statement:
If $a<b$ and $\{x_0,x_1, \cdots x_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ distinct, then there is one and only one set of weights $\{w_0, \cdots w_n \} $ such that $\int_a^b f(x) \ = \ \sum_{0 \leq k \leq n} w_k f(x_k)$ for any polynomial of degree $n$.

---

The weights aren't dependent of $f$, are they? We have to use $a,b$ and maybe $n$ to find the weights. First I rewrote the right hand side of the equality.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n f(x_k) \ = \ \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \sum_{k=0}^nw_k x_k^j
$$
we can rewrite the other side as
$
\sum_{j=0}^n a_j(b^j-a^j)
$. 
The equality must hold for polynomials of the shape $x^j$ for $0 \leq j \leq n$. Hence we can deduce the system:
$$
\forall j \in \{0, \cdots, n\}, \quad 
w_0x_0^j + w_1x_1^j + \cdots + w_n x_n^j \ = \ b^j-a^j 
$$
The equation can be shown with a matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0\\  
 x_0 & \cdots & x_n & b-a \\
   & \vdots &   & \vdots\\
 x_0^n & \cdots & x_n^n & b^n-a^n
\end{array}\right)$$
Can you tell me if this is the right way to deal with this problem, and how I can see that the vectors
$$
\{
\left( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
x_k \\
\vdots \\
x_k^n 
\end{array} \right)
\quad : \quad 0 \leq k \leq n\}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is sound. What remains to do to complete it is to note that the matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}  
 1 & \cdots & 1 \\  
 x_0 & \cdots & x_n \\
   & \vdots &   \\
 x_0^n & \cdots & x_n^n
\end{array}\right)$$ is called a [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and that its determinant is known to be $$\prod_{0\leqslant k\lt\ell\leqslant n}(x_\ell-x_k).$$ In particular, if the numbers $x_k$ are all distinct, the matrix is invertible and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that all $x_k$ are distinct.  Let $f_0,\ldots,f_n$ be the Lagrange basis polynomials for $x_0,\ldots,x_n$.  That is, each $f_k$ has degree $n$ and $f_k(x_m)=\delta_{km}$.  Now the weights are fixed since $$\int_a^b f_k(x)dx=\sum_{m=0}^nw_mf_k(x_m)=w_k.$$  For any polynomial $f$ of degree at most $n$ we find

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^b\left(\sum_{k=0}^nf(x_k)f_k(x)\right)dx=\sum_{k=0}^nw_kf(x_k)$$

as required.

Comment: Your way to go looks nice but I'd rather get an answer that goes ahead with my thoughts.